# Sort is not supported on binary data, object references and RealmList

Tags: java, realm

I'm working with Realm in android application. And i have the next issue:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: ec.com.se.demo.android.priceList, PID: 3557
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Argument: Sort is not supported on binary data, object references and RealmList.
                  at io.realm.internal.TableView.nativeSortMulti(Native Method)
                  at io.realm.internal.TableView.sort(TableView.java:665)
                  at io.realm.RealmQuery.findAllSorted(RealmQuery.java:1913)
                  at ec.com.se.demo.android.priceList.util.Queries.filterScrollData(Queries.java:68)
                  at ec.com.se.demo.android.priceList.tasks.FetchRowsTask.doInBackground(FetchRowsTask.java:51)
                  at ec.com.se.demo.android.priceList.tasks.FetchRowsTask.doInBackground(FetchRowsTask.java:21)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

My code is next:

```
public static ArrayList<Producto> filterScrollData(Integer initialPosition, Integer finalPosition, List<Tag> tags, final MainActivity main){
    ArrayList<Producto> result = new ArrayList<>();
    RealmQuery query = buscar(tags);
    RealmResults results= query.findAllSorted(new String[]{"tipo", "categoria", "proveedor", "nombre"}, new Sort[]{Sort.ASCENDING,Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING});
    if(initialPosition + 7 < query.count()){
        Iterator<Producto> iterator = results.subList(initialPosition, finalPosition).iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) result.add(new Producto(iterator.next()));
    }else{
        int aux=query.findAll().size();
        Iterator<Producto> iterator = results.subList(initialPosition, query.findAll().size()).iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) result.add(new Producto(iterator.next()));
        main.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(main, "No existen mas registros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to return a sorted list of objects, I was reviewing the Realm official documentation and findAllSorted () method receives as parameters a list of String which are the names of the fields and a list of Sort

Comment: How is your object defined? As the exception said, if one of fields `tipo`/`categoria`/`proveedor`/`nombre`is a type of `byte[]`/`RealmObject`/`RealmList`, sort won't work.

Comment: Well it says you can't sort by byte[], RealmObject field or RealmList field. Also this code had bad juju because it creates ArrayList but I don't see if it's rebuilt in a RealmChangeListener when change occurs to the underlying results.